# RC time picker in react redux applications

Tags: redux

How can I use "rc-time-picker 3.4.0" within the "react-redux" store to store its state? Can anyone give me the list of examples for using RC-time-picker in "react-redux" application?

Comment: Show us what have you tried. Present your code or research.